Can I change a 12 speed eagle cassete to a 9 speed CUES cassete?
I am looking for a bike to replace my current one, and I found one with a SRAM 12 speed eagle ttansmission. The thing is that I just changee the transmission on my current bike (9 speed Shimano CUES U400 cassete), and I was wondering if the 9 speed cassete from Shimano fits on that wheel hub.
The bike with tge SRAM transmition is a Trek Fuel EX 8 from 2020 if that helps answer the question.

If the bike has 12-spd Eagle, why in the world would you take that off?

@PaulH 2 reasons: first, the bike is second hand, and I don't know how well the drivetrain was maintained (been ridden for 4 years acordind to the current owner). So I would probably have to replace a few parts, which brings me to my second reason: higher maintanance and running costs. The Eagle drivetrain is way to expensive for what I usually ride, so it would be wasted on me. So I was planning to replace it with a CUES system that I already own, and sell it to someone that can use it to its full capacity

@Edy if you want to limit cost and maintenance, a full suspension MTB is probably not the best option (especially if you ride often on non technical stuff). Mid-range/Upper-range suspension and shocks need more service than entry level ones, and if you don't plan to service them, it might be good some time, but you'll reach a point where you'll be better without suspension.

@Renaud I don't have problems servicing forks and suspensions (because I'm doing that in house), but drivetrains are a different story, because I can't service a cassete

Eagle chains and cassettes are very durable. If the chain isn’t worn out, you’re good to go.

No, CUES cassettes are not compatible with other systems.
The compatibility of the cassette with the freehub, is only one part of the problem and even if you could technically change the cassette, it wouldn't shift properly anyway.

Why wouldn't it shift?

I know that the derailleur from sram wouldn't work with the CUES cassete. That's not the problem (because I wpuld change the derailleur as well). What I want to know is if the cassete itself (9 spd cues) fits on the hub that the current sram cassete is (because I don't know if 12 spd hubs can take 9 spd cassetes)

@Edy if the current cassette of the potential new bike has an 10T small sprocket, no, if it's an 11T, yes. But if the hub has interchangeable freehub bodies (usually not the case with OEM hubs, but common with third parties), you can technically purchase a compatible freehub body.
